# Normal operators and computing them

Tags: linear-algebra

H is an inner product space with inner product $( . , . )$ over the complex numbers, and $T∈L(H,H)$.  Let $R=T+T^*$, $S=T-T^*$ .   Supposing that T is normal and $T(\alpha)=(x+iy)\alpha$, how do I compute $(R∘S)(\alpha)$ in terms of $x,y,\alpha$ if I know that $R∘S=T∘T-T^*∘T^*$?  Thanks for any and all help!

Comment: It should be easy to compute $T\circ T$ right? So what's $T^{*}$? If you don't know, compute $T^{*}$. If you don't know how, try finding the definition and applying it to the situation you have.